# How to pop last three routes from the navigator stack in flutter

Tags: flutter, routes, navigation, navigator, flutter-navigation

**Scenario**

I'm navigating user to loginScreen/signUpScreen from different screens (Say destinationScreen, attractionScreens, reviewScreen etc) in the app and after loggingIn successfully, I want to pop him back to same screen from where he was navigated to the loginScreen/signupScreen.

So, I want to pop all the screens involved in the signup/login process say **3 screens**.

**What I've already tried**

I've already tried *navigator.popUntil* but it can work only if you want to pop back to a single screen every time like this:

Pushing route:

```
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    settings: RouteSettings(name: '/loginRedirect'),
      builder: (context) => AttractionScreen(
            attractionData: att,
          )),
);
```

Popping route in signInScreen:

```
Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/loginRedirect'));
```

But this scenario only works when you have to route to a single specific screen but in my case, I've to route to different screens depending on from where the user was directed to login screen.

**What I want to do now**

Now I want to have an implementation where after successful login, I pop the top three screens from the navigator stack which I search a lot but couldn't find any solution for that.
So, how can I pop the last routes from the navigator stack?

Answer (score 4):

I just got a solution which I was not sure on before.

I just need to call three times:

```
Navigator.pop(context)
```

like this:

```
if (needBackRedirect) {
    Navigator.of(context)..pop()..pop()..pop();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to pop until 3 screens from the navigation stack, take one variable and keep track of removed Routes. Then check if that count is reached to 3 then stop popping the routes.

1. add this variable:

```
   List<Route> arrayRoutes = [];
```

2. add this where you want to perform your pop logic :

```
    Navigator.popUntil(context, (Route<dynamic> route){
                          arrayRoutes.add(route);
                          if (arrayRoutes.length != 3) {
                            print('continue popping if length is not 3');
                            return true;
                          } else {
                            print('stop to pop when count is 3');
                            return false;
                          }
                        });
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply define the routes in the main.dart(appRoutes) file, use navigator **pushNamed** method to navigate between screen & to pop till any number of screen just use **popUnti** for example

```
Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) {
               return route.settings.name ==
                          'RouteName'; // Use defined route like Dashboard.routeName
     });
```